# How to recover one of WP email addresses?

Tags: email, email-verification

I am the WP admin of my own website. I recently noticed that I can't connect to one of my email addresses contact@[website.org]. It shows this error: Your sign-in settings don’t meet your organization’s 2-Step Verification policy. Contact your admin for more info." I can't manage to recover it and wouldn't find the solution online. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: I suggest speaking to your host about this. This is not something WordPress is responsible for. It's likely from a plugin, possibly one your host has installed. At the very least they should be able to disable the plugin.

Comment: WP doesn't come with 2 step verification out of the box

Comment: I hoped maybe being an admin on WP gives me access to these types of email addresses :( This website was managed by other person before, and I am pretty new to all of this :D

Comment: WordPress doesn't provide email, this will be managed using a separate service, usually via the host or a 3rd party that integrates with your domain, e.g. google work/gsuite/Office 360/Proton mail/etc

Comment: A quick search for that error message brings up Google Workspace help topics, contact whoever has the administrator access for your workspace, it's probably the person who used to manage it, eitherway WordPress knowledge or code won't be helpful to you here

Comment: Thank you so much!